# Allow-Eecode isn't properly working in EE4

Tags: ee4-upgrade, allow-eecode

Recently I upgraded an ExpressionEngine website from EE2 to EE4 which was using [Allow-Eecode](https://github.com/EllisLab/Allow-Eecode) plugin to parse snippet (Template Partial in EE4) into text content. Problem is that `template partial` is containing `{exp:query}` which is being outputted like plan text.

For example- my code is like:

```
{exp:allow_eecode query="y"}
{body}
{/exp:allow_eecode}
```

Its outputting:

```
....
....
{exp:query sql="SELECT table_column_1 FROM table_name WHERE table_column_2 = 'some-value'"}{table_column_1}{/exp:query}
....
....
```

Comment: Did you upgrade Allow-Eecode to an EE4 compatible version?  I have a site running under EE4 that also uses Allow-Eecode, and that is showing version 2.0.2.

Comment: @jcogs.eecms Yes, I am using latest v2.0.2.

Comment: No idea then... based on documentation it should work, but suspect this is one you'll have to go direct to Ellis for help with.  Sorry!